# Where do I get android images from?

Tags: android, image

I'm looking for an android repository where i can get certain images, like the record button image, camera flash image and the sort instead of making my own images. Or is there a rule that prohibits using specific android images on an app? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the images used in Android that are available for you to use are available in the SDK download in `/drawables`. From here you can make copies, edit them etc. to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant find the drawable folder in my sdk folder.

Comment: Check android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable and its siblings.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Assuming you're using Windows :-)

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I found it. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a repository of builtin Android drawables at http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/ . Their IDs are all exposed via the android.R.drawable class, so you're not technically prohibited from using these.

Comment: +1, although you _are_ technically prohibited from using some of the drawables. If you try to refer to them using android.R, the compiler will complain if the drawable is private (you can still copy those from the SDK)

Comment: Check the javadoc of android.R.drawable. Quite a bunch of those are perfectly public.

Comment: Yes, I did say some, not all :)